# Wordpress - Parent/Child Data

Tags: metadata, hierarchy, custom-taxonomy, wordpress

I have a song lyrics data structure that I'm developing and I've hit a dead end. To understand the basics of the structure, check out Justin Tadlock's article: [create a movie database using custom taxonomies](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/06/04/using-custom-taxonomies-to-create-a-movie-database)

This has been the closest thing to what I need.  But the requirement that breaks everything is that the user needs to sort the lyrics based on the parent album's release date.  Wordpress allows for a custom taxonomy to have meta data, so I have created a custom taxonomy: "album" with a [release_date] field.

Now, I'm stuck because I can't figure out how to write a WP_Query that will give me the following data:

```
Album Title - Released 2012
    Song Title - Track 1
    Song Title - Track 2
Album Title - Released 2011
    Song Title - Track 1
    Song Title - Track 2
```

All my research has led me to dead ends so I would appreciate anyone's help.  With this current dead end, I may have to resort to hand coding custom tables and doing raw SQL queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you can't do this directly, as I had this issue before and did quite a bit of research.  What I ended up have the wp_query loop create an array of posts, which I could then sort with any of the regular php array sorting functions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  It's disappointing that WordPress allows for taxonomy meta but doesn't provide a decent way to use it in a WP_Query.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  I'll mark your answer as accepted but I'd sure like to see some additional answers to my question.  Thanks for your help